# Minimization over every time step

Tags: cplex, opl

I am programming an optimizer for a peak load function. The issue is that I want to minimize my function over every time step. Currently he will just start the machines at the same time step and does not try to shift those starting points. My decision variable is the starting signal for the machines. For better understanding:

```
//parameters
 int m1=...; //number of machines
 int m2=...; //number of machines
 int m3=...; //number of machines
 int m4=...; //number of machines
 int m=m1+m2+m3+m4; //total number of machines
 int Parts1=...; //amount of parts from machines group 1
 int Parts2=...; //amount of parts from machines group 2
 int Parts3=...; //amount of parts from machines group 3
 int Parts4=...; //amount of parts from machines group 4
 int n=...; //number of time steps in overall simulation
 int p=...; // number of time steps in power cycle
 int k= n-p+2; //Declares the range to ensure that a machine can only start if it will finish in the shift
 float MaxLoad=...; 


 range machines = 1..m; // range over all machines
 range machines1 = 1..m1; //range over first machine group
 range machines2 = (m1+1)..(m1+m2); //range over second machine group
 range machines3 = (m1+m2+1)..(m1+m2+m3); //range over third machine group
 range machines4 = (m1+m2+m3+1)..(m1+m2+m3+m4); //range over fourth machine group
 range time = 1..n; //range over time steps
 range ptime = 1..p; //range over powercycle steps
 range sumbackStart = p..n;  //machine summation backwards (i-p+1) ensures that sum starts at 1 and not at -p !!
 range sumbackFinish = k..n; //no starts to the end of the shift if the machine will not finish the working piece

 float power [machines][ptime]=...;

 // variables
 dvar int+ x[machines][time];

// Optimization Problem
minimize sum (i in time) (sum(j in machines, inew in ptime: (i-inew+1) in time) x[j][i-inew+1]*power[j][inew]);

 subject to {   
    Range_binaryVariable: //Ensures that the decision variable is only 1 or 0
    forall (j in machines, i in time){
    0 <= x[j][i] <= 1; 
    }

    /*LimitLoadPeak: //Limits the maximum Peak
    forall (i in time){
    sum (j in machines, inew in ptime: (i-inew+1) in time) x[j][i-inew+1]*power[j][inew] <= 100;
    }*/

    PartStart: //Ensures that the machine only starts 
    forall (j in machines, i in sumbackStart){
    sum (inewnew in (i-p+1)..i) x[j][inewnew] <= 1; 
    }

    PartFinisher: //Ensures that the machines only start if they will finish during the given time steps or shift
    forall (j in machines){
    sum (inewnewnew in sumbackFinish) x[j][inewnewnew] <= 0; 
    }

    //Ensures that the work pieces, which need to be produced by the machine groups, will be produced
    PartminM1:
    Parts1 <= sum (j in machines1, i in time) x[j][i];

    PartminM2:
    Parts2 <= sum (j in machines2, i in time) x[j][i];

    PartminM3:
    Parts3 <= sum (j in machines3, i in time) x[j][i];

    PartminM4:
    Parts4 <= sum (j in machines4, i in time) x[j][i];


 }
```

I already implemented a peak limitation, but my function should actually do this by itself and try to shift the working process.

I hope you understand my problem and I would be really grateful for your help.

```
SheetConnection my_sheet ("OptiV7_Daten.xlsx");

n from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Information'!timesteps");

p from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Information'!powercycle");

MaxLoad from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Machine_Data_timesized'!MaxLoad");

Parts1 from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Information'!Parts1");

Parts2 from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Information'!Parts2");

Parts3 from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Information'!Parts3");

Parts4 from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Information'!Parts4");

m1 from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Information'!machines1");

m2 from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Information'!machines2");

m3 from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Information'!machines3");

m4 from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Information'!machines4");

power from SheetRead(my_sheet,"'Machine_Data_timesized'!Power");
```

Comment: Can you also share the .dat file ?

Comment: power is a mxn matrix. m machines over n timesteps. I want to minimize over every time step, but because of the sum over evey time step, it will of course only minimize the sum of every power consumption of every machine. I think I would need a loop, which tests every timestep to achieve a low level of power consumption in every step. But I do not know how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem, I solved it.
I changed the LimitLoadPeak constraint to the following:

```
// variables
 dvar int+ x[machines][time];
 dvar int+ MaxLoad;

// Optimization Problem last part ensures that when the machine is not running the idle power will be added
//minimize sum (i in time, j in machines, inew in ptime: (i-inew+1) in time) (x[j][i-inew+1]*power[j][inew] + Ipower[j]*(1-x[j][i-inew+1]));
minimize MaxLoad;
 subject to {   
    Range_binaryVariable: //Ensures that the decision variable is only 1 or 0
    forall (j in machines, i in time){
    0 <= x[j][i] <= 1; 
    }

    LimitLoadPeak: //Limits the maximum Peak
    forall (i in time){
    (sum (j in machines, inew in ptime: (i-inew+1) in time)  (x[j][i-inew+1]*power[j][inew]))^2 <= MaxLoad;
    }
```

MaxLoad is defined as a variable and the square of the sum ensures that small deviations also influence the result.